# Timestamp error in facebook analytics for apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-analytics

I am using facebook analytics for apps and want to download my data using export api but i am getting an error invalid_request" "(#3004) Request interval smaller than 3600 seconds i don't know how to correctly use the time stamp in export api of facebook analytics for apps. Please guide me through

Comment: I got it , I was a bit confused with Timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Please be familiar with below article: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/export

The timestamps (both start_ts and end_ts) are standard Unix epoch in UTC, use below tool to convert human time to the timestamp:
https://www.epochconverter.com/

The interval between end_ts and start_ts should be at least 1 hour = 3600 seconds.